# changing text colour when a condition is met

Tags: html, fonts

does anyone know how I would do this within an HTML-5 web based application? ie I need to change the font colour of a name when a button is pressed. It's for an application that easily shows when players are on or off court in a tennis tournament.
so far I have an excel document of all the players loaded in to an html, this is one of the names for instance:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tSQ4.png

and buttons as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpMMT.png

so I assume I could write an if condition that states if that button is on, then the player's name goes red or something..
I'm also struggling with layout, considering the names are in a table, the button just stays above the table wherever I put it.
Any help is much appreciated,
Louis.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I have no idea where to start, so nothing. As for j08691 - please elaborate, thank you.

Comment: How about posting details about this "condition"? Your HTML and anything else you feel like sharing could be useful too.

Comment: @j08691 I have edited the post in response to your comment, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href='#changeColor'>Click me!</a>

#chaneColor:target{
    color:red;
}
```

Would work... as would a million other things. Please post more details. At least the markup of the page you want this to happen on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a stylesheet -- [read this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html) -- then you can do soemthing like this

```
button:active{
color:red;
}
```

or whatever color...doesn't have to be red. Now this example is really simple, because it will change the color of the text written on the button..but you can use stylesheets for many, many more things

Comment: thanks very much - that will be very helpful. Another question, I basically have a spreadsheet of names, each of whom has to have a button next to their names, and when that button is pressed their name turns red. Would I have to repeat the code for each of the names, or is there a quicker way of doing it?

Comment: I think he wants to change the colour of another element when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple solution would be to use JQuery:

```
$('#your_button').click(function() {
    $('#your_element').css('color','red');
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UcLSG/5/